# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).css is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

Estaba analizando un script para borrar posts y demases de facebook mediante consola, pero a la hora de ejecutarlo me sale el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).css is not a function
```

En esta línea:

```
$('[placeholder="Search Facebook"]').css('color','#fff').css('background-color','#000');
```

Para ver esto, lo primero que hago es ir al `ActivityLog` del perfil de `Facebook`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código completo:

```
var deleted = 0;
function delete_new() {

    $('[placeholder="Search Facebook"]').css('color','#fff').css('background-color','#000');

    try {
        throttle = parseFloat(throttle);
    }
    catch(ex) {
        throttle = 1;
    }
    active = 1;
    chrome.storage.local.set({active: 1}, function() {});

    var all_action_options = [];
    var dots = -1;
    var dots_txt = '';
    set_interval_id = setInterval(function(){
        // remove empties - links only
        $('[aria-label="List of Activity Log Items"]').find('[role="link"]').each(function(){
            if($(this).parent().parent().find('[aria-label="Action options"]').length == 0) {
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            }
        });

        dots = dots + 1;
        if(dots == 4) {
            dots = 0;
        }
        var msg = 'Running';
        dots_txt = '';
        for(var i=0; i < dots; i++) {
            msg += '.';
            dots_txt += '.';
        }
        try {
            if($("span:visible:contains('This Page Isn't Available Right Now'):first").length > 0) {
                 myreload2();
            }
            if($("span:visible:contains('Query Error'):first").length > 0) {
                $("div[role*='button']:visible:contains('OK'):first").click();
            }
        }
        catch(ex) {}
        
        deleted = deleted + 1;

    if(1 > $('[aria-label*="List of Activity Log Items"] h2:first').parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('[aria-label*="Action options"]:visible:first').length) {
            $('[aria-label*="List of Activity Log Items"] h2:first').parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
        }

        var action_options = $('[aria-label*="Action options"]:visible:first');
        $('[aria-label*="Action options"]:visible:first').parent().parent().css('opacity', 0.5);
        $('[aria-label*="Action options"]:visible:first').parent().parent().css('background-color', '#fee');
        //$('[aria-label*="Action options"]:visible:first').parent().parent().css('background-color', '#ddd');

        var del_this = true;
        try {
            if(contains || contains_not) {
                del_this = false;
                $('[aria-label*="Action options"]:visible:first').parent().parent().css('background-color', '#efe');
            }
            if(contains != '' && action_options.parent().parent().html().toLowerCase().indexOf(contains.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                del_this = true;
                $('[aria-label*="Action options"]:visible:first').parent().parent().css('background-color', '#fee');
            }
            if(contains_not != '' && action_options.parent().parent().html().toLowerCase().indexOf(contains_not.toLowerCase()) == -1) {
                del_this = true;
                $('[aria-label*="Action options"]:visible:first').parent().parent().css('background-color', '#fee');
            }
            
        }
        catch(ex){console.log(ex);}
        var activity_log_html = $('[aria-label*="Action options"]:visible:first').parent().prev('div').html();
    if(all_action_options.includes(activity_log_html) || !del_this) {
            $('[placeholder="Search Facebook"]').val('Skipping'+dots_txt);
            $('[aria-label*="Action options"]:visible:first').parent().parent().remove();
            return;
    }
        $('[placeholder="Search Facebook"]').val('Deleting'+dots_txt);
        all_action_options.push(activity_log_html);
        action_options.click();

        //action_options.parent().css('background-color', 'yellow');
        //$(this).find('i').next('div').click();
        setTimeout(function(){
            //action_options.parent().parent().slideUp();
            //action_options.parent().css('background-color', '#ffcccc');
            //$('[data-testid="Keycommand_wrapper_ModalLayer"]:visible:first > div > div > div > div > div > div > div').click();               
            var search_span = [
                'Move to trash', 
                'Hide from Timeline',
                'Remove Reaction',
                'Delete',
                'Unlike'
            ];
            var found_span = false;
            for(var i=0;i<search_span.length;i++) {
                if($("[role*='menu'] span:visible:contains('"+search_span[i]+"'):first").length > 0) {
                    found_span = true;
                }
            }
            $('[aria-label*="Delete"]:visible').click();
            $('[aria-label*="Move to Trash"]:visible').click();
            if(found_span) {
                $("[role*='menu'] span:visible:contains('Remove Reaction'):first").click();
                $("[role*='menu'] span:visible:contains('Delete'):first").click();
                $("[role*='menu'] span:visible:contains('Unlike'):first").click();
                $("[role*='menu'] span:visible:contains('Move to trash'):first").click();
                $("[role*='menu'] span:visible:contains('Hide from Timeline'):first").click();
            }
            else {
                action_options.parent().parent().remove();
            }
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('[aria-label*="Delete"]:visible').click();
            $('[aria-label*="Move to Trash"]:visible').click();
                $('body').click();
                
            },300*throttle);
        },500*throttle);                
        
        try {
            chrome.storage.local.get(['active'], function(result) {
                active = result.active; 
            });
        }
        catch(ex) {}
        if(active != 1) {
            $('#posts-deleted').html(deleted);
            clearInterval(set_interval_id)
        }

        // make sure we have stop button
        if($('#fe-stop-delete-btn').length == 0) {
            var del_btn = '<div id="fe-stop-delete-btn" style="opacity: 0.7;background-color: #006f94;position: fixed;bottom: 10px;height: 50px;'+
                                    'z-index: 999999;'+
                                      'width: 100%;'+
                                      'text-align:  center;'+
                                      'color:  #fff;'+
                                      'font-size: 30px;'+
                                      'line-height: 48px;'+
                                      'cursor: pointer;'+
                                      'border: 1px solid #555;'+
                                        '" >Stop!</div>';
            $('body').append(del_btn)
            $('#fe-stop-delete-btn').click(function(){
                stop_delete();$(this).remove();
            });
        }
    },1000*throttle);
}
```

A este mismo lo añado a la consola y lo ejecuto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aparece el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Qué versión de jquery usas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero puede que no tengas jquery correctamente importado. Comprueba que cargas jquery antes que tu script.

Segundo, ¿Por qué elijes el elemento placeholder=X para identificar tu objeto?
Suponiendo que este es el código HTML o similar:

```
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Facebook">
```

Añade un ID o un class al elemento y lo seleccionas con el, ahí va un ejemplo:

```
<input id="buscador" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Facebook">
```

Teniendo ese input ahora puedes hacer:

```
$('#buscador').css('color','#fff').css('background-color','#000');
```

Answer (score 0):

ese tipo de error me ha pasado generalmente cuando no esta bien importado la libreria de jquery o porque la version importada no soporta esa sintaxis o falta importar algun plugin, como jquery-ui.